# configure a jQuery plugin for Google Maps

Tags: jquery, google-maps

I am using this plugin:
http://smartystreets.com/kb/liveaddress-api/plugin/configure

The Code:

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
  <head>
   <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />

   <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

   <script src="//d79i1fxsrar4t.cloudfront.net/jquery.liveaddress/2.4/jquery.liveaddress.min.js">   </script>

 <script>jQuery.LiveAddress("my key");</script>

   <script type="text/javascript">
   var liveaddress = $.LiveAddress({
    key: 'my key',
   debug: true,
    addresses: [{
    id: 'mySubmitButton',      // IDs are not part of the address
    street: '#street_add',
    street2: '#street2',    // Not all these fields are required
    city: '#city',
    state: '#state',
    zipcode: '#postcode',
    country: '#country'
   },
   {

   }]
    });

     </script>  


   </head>
   <body>
    <div id="panel">
       <form action="" name="" method="post">
           <input id="addresses" type="hidden" value="">
           Street Address<input id="street_add" type="textbox" value="" class="address">  <br />
           City<input id="city" type="textbox" value="" class="address"><br />
           State<input id="state" type="textbox" value="" class="address"><br />
           Zipcode<input id="postcode" type="textbox" value="" class="address"><br />
           Country<input id="country" type="textbox" value="" class="address"><br />
           <input type="submit" value="submit" id="#mySubmitButton" />
     </form>
    </div>
    <div id="map-canvas" style="height:40%;top:30px;"></div>
   </body>
   </html>
```

It seems that I need to configure this to get it to work, according to the instructions. I see that LiveAddress function is being called, and then I am adding the configuration part (var live address)
Is this being initialized and configured properly, and does it seem like it will connect to the form?

Comment: most def you need this property filled in `key: "HtmlKey"`

Answer (score 0):

Here is one method of doing it based on the documentation. first you initialize the liveaddress object and do the mapping in the same instance. At the moment you have done it separately. which is unnecessary.

```
var l = $.LiveAddress({
    key: 'HTML_KEY',
    debug: true,
    addresses: [{
        id: 'billing',      // IDs are not part of the address
        street: '#street1',
        street2: '#street2',    // Not all these fields are required
        city: '#city',
        state: '#state',
        zipcode: '#zip',
        country: '#country'
    },
    {
        id: 'shipping',     // IDs are optional, but can be helpful
        street: '#addrTb'
    }]
});
```

then all you have to do is call the `verify` method

```
l.verify('billing');
```